# C# How to do an authorization method

Tags: c#, http, http-post, postman, adal

I was needing to retrieve a entity record from dynamics finance and operations and I did it in Postman but now I need to the same with code. I am using asp.net core and when I try to retrieve the entity the response gives me HTML. I figure out is because the authorization needs to be the same as the postman that is a post operation with grant_type, clientId, client secret and Resource.

How can I do post operation in C# with grant_type, clientId, client secret and Resource parameters to get the access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options. In either of the cases, you might want to give a quick read to [Microsoft identity platform and the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

- Using [MSAL client library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/) (note ADAL is deprecated now). Below is a quick code snippet. Full example can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/2-Call-OwnApi/daemon-console). Also, read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#client-credentials).

```cs
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("<client id>")
                    .WithClientSecret("<client secret>")
                    .WithAuthority(new Uri("<authority>")) // authority = https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}
                    .Build();
// With client credentials flows the scopes is ALWAYS of the shape "resource/.default", as the 
// application permissions need to be set statically (in the portal or by PowerShell), and then granted by a tenant administrator
var scopes = new string[] { "<scope>" };
var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
var accessToken = result.AccessToken;
// call api with http authorization header
// Authorization: Bearer <Access Token>
```

- Using REST API directly from C# code using httpClient.

```cs
var client = new HttpClient(); // just for example I am creating the client inline
var result = await client.PostAsync(
                     "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token",
                     new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                    {
                        {"client_id", "<client id>"},
                        {"grant_type", "client_credentials"},
                        {"client_secret", "<client secret>"},
                        {"scope", "<scope>"},
                    }));

var responseBody = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
// response would be a JSON, just extract token from it
var accessToken = (string)JToken.Parse(responseBody)["access_token"];
// call api with http authorization header
// Authorization: Bearer <Access Token>
```

Comment: thanks so much it workek, i didnt know that adal wad deprecated